# Android Studio Warning on my app: app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm trying to remove warnings in my app but this is a warning that I cannot remove... I don't really know what that means, let me know if you have an idea. Thank you so much!

> ```
> > Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
> WARNING: Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 20.0.5594570.
> Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 20.0.5594570.
> Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libpl_droidsonroids_gif.so, libpl_droidsonroids_gif.so,
> ```
>
> libpl_droidsonroids_gif.so, libpl_droidsonroids_gif.so,
> libpl_droidsonroids_gif.so, libpl_droidsonroids_gif.so,
> libpl_droidsonroids_gif.so.
>
> ```
> > Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
> > Task :app:packageDebug
> > Task :app:assembleDebug
>
>
>
> > Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> WARNING: Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 20.0.5594570.
> Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 20.0.5594570.
>
> Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 20.0.5594570.
> ```

This is my build.gradle (module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.android"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    implementation "com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5"
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.Shashank02051997:FancyGifDialog-Android:1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.thomper:sweet-alert-dialog:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.shadowalker77:wp7progressbar:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.15.3'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.faltenreich:skeletonlayout:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure Your NDK in "Project settings" -> "SDK Location" -> "Android NDK location".
If You haven't an NDK, then go to Tools -> SDK Manager -> Tab "SDK Tools" and select NDK (side by side).

Answer (score 1):

Modify app/build.gradle with adding ndkVersion. I have used below version. You have to use your compatible version "20.0.5594570"

[image]